# Drilling Rigs Rule-Based Styling

Tags: qgis-3, style, rule-based

[image]

I am trying to do rule-based styling for active drilling rigs in the United States.

Basically, I want to have categorized styling (different colored dots) for all companies (field = "OpCompany") with greater than x active rigs.

For companies with less than x active rigs, I would like them all to be the same color dots.

It is important to note that the data set (picture attached) shows each rig individually, so I am trying to find a way to write an expression/ rule that counts the # of duplicate "Operator Company Name" values in the "Operator Company Name" field.

I have searched extensively online, however cannot find a solution to my problem. Any ideas here?

Comment: You just need to use rule-based styling. Here you can define the rules for each category and assign a symbol to each (pull down for categorized / graduated / rule-based)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! How do I make the rule so that it counts the # of duplicate company names in the "OpCompany" field? (This represents the # of active rigs in my data set)

Answer (score 1):

First create two rules, one for companies with less than x rigs and other for companies with more than x rigs. here is an example with sn<25 and sn>=25. [image]. After this click the rule with greater and click **Refine Selected Rules** and click **Add Categories to Rule**.[image]. Then classify by the column name. Don't worry about having entries from other groups. Remove if you want. Final rules should be like this. [image] Apply.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you!

Comment: How do I make the rule so that it counts the # of duplicate company names in the "OpCompany" field? (This represents the # of active rigs in my data set). The data set lists each rig separately. I will attach to the original post.

Comment: use count or count_distinct function in expression builder while making rules.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the expression would look like in the expression builder given the picture attached above? The field name I am counting is "OpCompany".

Comment: The `sn>=25` rule shouldn't have its own symbology, otherwise it will hide the categorized symbols nested underneath.